# Python How to remove \n present in between the element of a list?

Tags: python, list

***My list looks like this.***

**credentials** = ['MANISH CHAUHAN', '03:00 P.M. to 06:00 P.M.(IST)', '22.07.2021', 'DPG Institute Of Technology And\nManagementSector- 34 Near Hero Honda\nChowk NH- 8 Gurugram Haryana - 122001', '']

I am trying to remove \n from the elements [-2] of the list.

It is printing element like this =

```
DPG Institute Of Technology And
ManagementSector- 34 Near Hero Honda
Chowk NH- 8 Gurugram Haryana - 122001
```

I want it to be like this =

```
DPG Institute Of Technology And ManagementSector- 34 Near Hero Honda Chowk NH- 8 Gurugram Haryana - 122001
```

Comment: `credentials[-2] = credentials[-2].replace("\n", " ")`

Comment: Consider using the replace() function that's built in to Python strings

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str.replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) function followed by [`.join()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) to get the output.

```
lists=['MANISH CHAUHAN', '03:00 P.M. to 06:00 P.M.(IST)', '22.07.2021', 'DPG Institute Of Technology And\nManagementSector- 34 Near Hero Honda\nChowk NH- 8 Gurugram Haryana - 122001', '']

lists[-2]=lists[-2].replace('\n','')
print(' '.join(lists))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html?highlight=map#2to3fixer-map) and [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace):

```py
lst = ['MANISH CHAUHAN', '03:00 P.M. to 06:00 P.M.(IST)', '22.07.2021', 'DPG Institute Of Technology And\nManagementSector- 34 Near Hero Honda\nChowk NH- 8 Gurugram Haryana - 122001', '']

lst = list(map(lambda i: i.replace('\n', ''), lst))

rst = ' '.join(lst)
```